# does anybody know how to set the color of the border of text in processing

Tags: text, processing

I think there is no `textBorder();` and `Stroke();` does not work. any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This makes a pretty good 1px stroke by drawing the text four times in the stroke color, then once in the fill color:

```
void draw() {
  textSize(30);
  textWithBorder("text", 255, 0, 15, 30); 
}

void textWithBorder(String string, int strokecolor, int fillcolor, int x, int y) {
  fill(strokecolor);
  text(string, x-1, y); 
  text(string, x+1, y); 
  text(string, x, y-1); 
  text(string, x, y+1); 
  fill(fillcolor);
  text(string, x, y); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue

you have to print two texts with different font sizes over each other, one with the border color and on top of that and slightly smaller the one with the fill color.

you can write a basic `textWithBorder(...)` function.